# swift Xcode For loop for Array

Tags: swift, xcode, loops, for-loop

i do have the next code that does its job but i´m looking a way to make it more elegant

```
var collectionAnswers = [0,0,1]

if collectionAnswers[0] == 1 {

        button1Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {

        button1Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    if collectionAnswers[1] == 1 {

        button2Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {

        button2Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    if collectionAnswers[2] == 1 {

        button3Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {

        button3Oulet.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

so far i have come with the next code but i can't make it to work

can you please help me ,,, kind of stuck here

```
for (index,element) in collectionAnswers.enumerated() {

        switch index {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            if element == 0 {print("Bad")}
            else {

                for button in collectionOfButtons {

                    if index == button.tag && element == 1 {

                        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

                    } else {

                        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                    }
                }

                print("OK")
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the HELP!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for making some working code more elegant. This is on-topic for the code review site.

Comment: Forget the if then else.  Use a Switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, create an additional array containing the button *ou(t)lets*

```
let collectionAnswers = [0, 0, 1]
let buttons = [button1Oulet, button2Oulet, button3Oulet]

for (index, answer) in collectionAnswers.enumerated() {
    buttons[index].backgroundColor = (answer == 0) ? .red : .green
}
```

Comment: Thanks man ,,, works perfect,, i really appreciate your help